# How to link an inaccessible directory such that it is accessible?

Tags: linux, remote-access

In one system I have the following file system organization.

```
/home/user1/MyDocs/
/scratch/user1/
```

Above `/scratch/user1/` is accessible to all systems on the network, but `/home/user1/` is not. I want to make `MyDocs` accessible too. How do I do that without creating a copy?

I tired creating symlink `MyDocs` in `/scratch/user1/` but that seems not to help when accessed from remote systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that a symlink doesn't work is that  a symlink basically just says "hey, you need to look in '/home/user1/MyDocs' instead. And since that's not accessible, that's not going to work.

One way is to do the linking the other way around, i.e. make `/scratch/user1` a real directory and then symlink that to `/home/user1/MyDocs`.

Another one is to remount it using --bind, like this:

```
mount --bind /home/user1/MyDocs /scratch/user1
```

But you really want to read the man page for mount thoroughly before trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with this command, and read about it before using it:

```
mount --bind olddir newdir
```